# Mule Mapping xml lists to a java Map (Key, Value) for CRM Dynamics online

Tags: mule, transform, transformation, mule-studio, dataweave

I have XML input which needs to be converted into java map to be used as an input for CRM online connector(to create account).

**Example input : I am giving only part of xml for which I am facing issues**

```
<account>
 <identification>
 <accountId>String</accountId>
 </identification>

 <addresses>
     <address>
         <type>type1</type>
         <name>name1</name>
         <street>street1</street>
         <communication>
             <phone>phone1</phone>
             <phoneExtension>phoneExtension1</phoneExtension>
             <phoneCountry>phoneCountry1</phoneCountry>
             <fax>fax1</fax>
             <faxExtension>faxExtension1</faxExtension>
             <faxCountry>faxCountry1</faxCountry>
             <email>email1</email>
             <website>website1</website>
         </communication>
         </address>
     <address>
         <type>type2</type>
         <name>name2</name>
         <street>street2</street>
         <communication>
             <phone>phone2</phone>
             <phoneExtension>phoneExtension2</phoneExtension>
             <phoneCountry>phoneCountry2</phoneCountry>
             <fax>fax2</fax>
             <faxExtension>faxExtension2</faxExtension>
             <faxCountry>faxCountry2</faxCountry>
             <email>email1</email>
             <website>website2</website>
         </communication>
         </address>
     <address>
         <type>type3</type>
         <name>name3</name>
         <street>street3</street>
         <communication>
             <phone>phone3</phone>
             <phoneExtension>phoneExtension3</phoneExtension>
             <phoneCountry>phoneCountry3</phoneCountry>
             <fax>fax3</fax>
             <faxExtension>faxExtension3</faxExtension>
             <faxCountry>faxCountry3</faxCountry>
             <email>email3</email>
             <website>website3</website>
         </communication>
         </address>
 </addresses>
```

As you can see I have three adresses inside which is an array of address and All has same tags .

I want to transform this xml into java map to create an account on CRM Dynamics online. But the problem is, in CRM we have totally different structure. We have addresses in form of key value pairs. So from above address input we have below mapping

```
address1_type : type1
address1_name : name1
address1_street : street1
address1_phone : phone1
address1_phoneExtension : phoneExtension1
address1_phoneCountry : phoneCountry1
address1_fax : fax1
address1_faxExtension : faxExtension1
address1_faxCountry : faxCountry1
address1_email : email1
address1_website : website1

address2_type : type2
address2_name : name2
address2_street : street2
address2_phone : phone2
address2_phoneExtension : phoneExtension2
address2_phoneCountry : phoneCountry2
address2_fax : fax2
address2_faxExtension : faxExtension2
address2_faxCountry : faxCountry2
address2_email : email2
address2_website : website2

address3_type : type3
address3_name : name3
address3_street : street3
address3_phone : phone3
address3_phoneExtension : phoneExtension3
address3_phoneCountry : phoneCountry3
address3_fax : fax3
address3_faxExtension : faxExtension3
address3_faxCountry : faxCountry3
address3_email : email3
address3_website : website3
```

**Is there a way to transform input address array into a required map key values? I am looking for a way to do it with dataweave if possible.**

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: btw I am trying to transform xml lists to a java map with dataweave . As you know java map has unique keys but xml list will have same keys in dataweave but i want dynamic keys to be created as you can see in the second part of the question ..please  let me know if it's not detailed enough

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.This might be helpful for someone

transformation is possible while looping through list and creating dynamic map keys in dataweave with specific index.

```
 %dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{ //tells DW that output should be object i.e. HashMap
 ( //tells DW to use key-value from below mapping
     payload.account.addresses map ((value,index) -> {
         ("address" ++ (index+1) ++ "_type"): value.type, // Parenthesis around key tells DW to evaluate contents and use the result as key
         ("address" ++ (index+1) ++ "_name"): value.name,
         ("address" ++ (index+1) ++ "_street"): value.street
     })
   )
}
```